# Temporary collection in an OrientDB query using the intersect function

Tags: orientdb

I would like to build a query that is conceptually like:

```
SELECT INTERSECT(["12","34"],(SELECT custom_id FROM USER))
```

the first collection ideally is made on the fly. otherwise is it possible to make a temporary collection? What would be the limits of this collection; could it contain thousands of elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a DB to test your case and there are different ways to proceed.
Structure:

- Classes: User;
- Properties: custom_id as integer (created on User);
- Indexes: User.custom_id UNIQUE (I advise to create an index to speed up the operations in case you work with thousands of records).

In your example the parameters are manually passed and compared with the result of a query and you can try this:

```
select intersect($a.left, $b.right)
let $a = (select [12, 34] as left), 
    $b = (select custom_id as right from User)
```

otherwise you can use only queries to get the results

```
select intersect($a.left, $b.right)
let $a = (select custom_id as left from User where custom_id = 12 or custom_id = 34), 
    $b = (select other_id as right from otherClass)
```

or the third way is to build both lists on the fly

```
select intersect($a.left, $b.right)
let $a = (select [12, 34] as left), 
    $b = (select [1, 5, 9, 12, 28, 34, 45] as right)
```

Answer (score 0):

Executing

```
select $a
let $a = (select [12, 34] as mylist)
```

Returns

```
[{"mylist":[12,34]}]
```

Executing

```
select $a.mylist
let $a = (select [12, 34] as mylist)
```

Returns

```
[[12,34]]
```

Executing

```
select $a.mylist[0]
let $a = (select [12, 34] as mylist)
```

Returns

```
[12,34]
```

Executing

```
select intersect($a.left[0], $b.right[0])
let $a = (select [12, 34] as left), 
    $b = (select [1, 5, 9, 12, 28, 34, 45] as right)
```

Returns

```
[34, 12]
```

So going from a previous answer, the [0] suffix is key to get the correct reference for $a. The list() function is needed to combine the result set rows into an list/array.

**The solution is:**

```
select intersect($a.left[0], $b.right[0])
let $a = (select [12, 34] as left), 
    $b = (select list(custom_id) as right from User)
```